# Mounting a windows partition: worked once now cant access

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have a hard disk from a windows 8 machine that I am trying to recover some documents from.

I plugged the drive into my ubuntu laptop and could easily access the files on the windows partition (there are several recovery partitions as well), after leaving the machine for a few moments once I returned to it I can no longer access the windows partition, it appears no longer to be mounted and wont mount/cannot be accessed on another ubuntu machine.

When I open 'disks' and select the 1 TB volume I am trying to access 'disks' hangs. Ubuntu doesn't spit out any errors when trying to open the windows partition it just does nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: Assuming you can repeat the behaviour (the unresponsive Windows partition), can you please include the output of `sudo dmesg`, `cat /proc/mounts`, and `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: @MarkKirby: Why would that problem occur suddenly after leaving the mounted drive and file system unattended for a while? It's not like Microsoft can secretly place a hibernation file onto the drive during OP's absence.

Comment: @DavidFoerster You have a good point, I seem to have been a bit quick to close this one, I actually think I will retract my vote, well spotted.

Comment: Actually, replace `fdisk -l` with `parted -l` (unless the drive has an MBR partition table).